# I'm getting an InternalServerError when uploading a .p12 certificate to the APNS in the Azure Portal

Tags: azure-notificationhub

So this morning I created 2 apple certificates (dev and prod), and exported them to `.p12` files to upload them to the `Azure Portal` in the `APNS` notification hub.

This morning I was able to upload successfully the production cert, but in the afternoon I tried uploading the dev `.p12` cert and I'm getting an:

```
{"error":{"message":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","code":"InternalServerError"}}
```

Is it just that the server is having issues?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed. Could you retry this operation ?

Comment: Hello Sateesh. Yeah, looks like it was a problem on their side and I can upload my certs just fine.